# seetting cron on server issue with saving and exiting

Tags: cron

I am new to servers and I want to setup cron. I want to check if cron is running on the server. To do that I use the following command.

```
crontab -l
```

I looked on Google for a command to check what is set to run in crontab. This is the command I think I should use.

```
crontab -u root -e
```

When I do that I get an editor. A picture of the editor is provided in the following screenshot.

[ssh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKHLg.png)

I pasted the command below.

```
5 * * * * root /bin/sh /var/www/mour/cron.sh
```

Now I am stuck. How do I save the crontab?

Comment: On the screenshot you provide the default editor is vi which you can save by pressing "esc" then colon + wp it will look like this :wp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this actually isn't a question about crontab, more so a question about your text editor.  If you're just checking which crons are on running on your machine run the `crontab -l` command like you did.

If you want to actually edit the crontab file to, say, add or remove a cron, you can `crontab -e`.  And then depending on your OS or your settings, it may ask you which text editor you want to use or it may default to one.  Not 100% sure, but the screenshot you provided looks like the editor might be [vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Tutorial).  If it is, after you are done editing the file, you can save and quit the file by entering `:wq`

Answer (score 1):

To "check" if cron is running, that's very much depends on your OS (since you didn't provide that information, I'll provide these two: `RHEL6` - `service crond status`, `RHEL7` - `systemctl status crond`. To check which `cronjobs` are scheduled, you should use `-l`, like this:

```
$ crontab -l
* 12 * * Tue    /root/backup.sh
$
```

To learn more about VIM, read [Vim documentation : vim online](http://www.vim.org/docs.php). You might also want to explore other editor(s), if VIM is too complicated for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all to edit the cron use command

```
crontab -e
```

In your case you are using vi editor

to edit the text use **i**

use **esc** to exit editing mode, and press **:x** to save and exit, **:x!** is used to save forcefully.

incase you dont want to save and wants to exit without saving use **:q** and **:q!** is used to exit forcefully.

To check the cronjob what you have scheduled use command

```
crontab -l
```

To check whether it is executing properly or not you can the check the logs of cron jobs. Location of cronlogs is

```
/var/log/cron
```

use command

```
cat /var/log/cron
```

In your case use

```
cat /var/log/cron | grep cron.sh
```

Comment: press :x to save and exit, :x! does not seems work do i need to press ctrl +x

Comment: just need should i use : 5 * * * *  /bin/sh /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.sh

or */5 * * * *  /bin/sh /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.sh

Comment: First press esc to exit the editing mode. After that press **:x** to save and exit.

Comment: for your second query you need be pretty clear so that i can evaluate.